# Could not bind the array value in the excel column, getting #NAME? in a excel exported using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
  public exportExcel(
    fileName: string,
    header: string[],
    data: any[],
    sheetName: string
  ) {
    let arr: Array<any[]> = [];
    data = Array.of(data);
    arr[0] = header;

    for (let i = 1; i < data[0].length + 1; i++) {
      arr[i] = [];
      let temp = data[0];
      for (let obj of Object.values(temp[i - 1])) {
        arr[i].push(obj);
      }
    }

    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(arr);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, sheetName);
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
```

I am trying to export writingCompanyName array value to the single column in a excel, when tested in a console I get the array response properly but when exporting i am getting as #NAME?.
Please help to find where I am doing wrong

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
JSON - 

writingCompanies: Array(2)
0:
writingCompanyId: 1
writingCompanyName: "test verbiage1"
__proto__: Object
1:
writingCompanyId: 2
writingCompanyName: "test verbiage2"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
```

Comment: can you put  export code here. ?

Comment: Added the excel export code. Thank you!

Comment: I can't see you have used item  anywhere  in the code ? also always put data in the question so that it can be replicated

Comment: Added the map code. Thank you!